# Undesired output from write.table() function in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file which i loaded into R using read.csv and performed some operation. And, now I need to write it back to csv format. However the problem is that, the write.table() function  does not produces the require output.

Initial Data:

```
id,name,Households,Population,Total Male,Total Female
0,Nepal,5427302,26494504,12849041,13645463
1,Taplejung,26509,127461,60552,66909
2,Panchthar,41196,191817,90186,101631
3,Ilam,64502,290254,141126,149128
4,Jhapa,184552,812650,385096,427554
```

Final Output with write.table()

```
"id","name","Households","Population","SexRatio"
"1",0,"Nepal",5427302,26494504,94.1634666408901
"2",1,"Taplejung",26509,127461,90.499036004125
"3",2,"Panchthar",41196,191817,88.7386722555126
"4",3,"Ilam",64502,290254,94.634139799367
"5",4,"Jhapa",184552,812650,90.0695584651295
```

how can I get the final output in input format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that your main complaint is about the "row names" that have been appended to the output and the quotes around all the strings.

If that is the case, look into the arguments `row.names` and `quote` in `write.table()` (and thus, `write.csv()`) and set them to `FALSE` when you are writing your files.

Here's an example, assuming that your data in R is called `inData`.

First, we'll write `inData` to a file with the default arguments to `write.csv`. Note the row names and the quoted strings.

```
write.csv(inData, file = "oldfile.csv")

cat(readLines("oldfile.csv"), sep="\n")
# "","id","name","Households","Population","Total.Male","Total.Female"
# "1",0,"Nepal",5427302,26494504,12849041,13645463
# "2",1,"Taplejung",26509,127461,60552,66909
# "3",2,"Panchthar",41196,191817,90186,101631
# "4",3,"Ilam",64502,290254,141126,149128
# "5",4,"Jhapa",184552,812650,385096,427554
```

Here's the same thing with `inData` being written with the arguments I've mentioned set to `FALSE`:

```
write.csv(inData, file = "newfile.csv", 
          row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

cat(readLines("newfile.csv"), sep="\n")
# id,name,Households,Population,Total.Male,Total.Female
# 0,Nepal,5427302,26494504,12849041,13645463
# 1,Taplejung,26509,127461,60552,66909
# 2,Panchthar,41196,191817,90186,101631
# 3,Ilam,64502,290254,141126,149128
# 4,Jhapa,184552,812650,385096,427554
```